# Best way to deal with surge in current from DC motors

Tags: batteries, current

I have a Li-po battery 12V 9800mAh (typical current 2.4A) which powers a 4WD drone using 4 DC motors (which I have not yet characterized).

Driving the motors from still to max speed without transients will cause a spike in current consumption that goes beyond what the battery can supply.

I can (and most likely have to) use the SW to make the transition gradual, so that the peak current is somehow manageable.

However so far I only performed empirical attempts and I think most likely they will be sub-optimal, depending on the level of charge of the battery.

After googling, I still couldn't find an ultimate answer to how to address this problem.

Some advice says to put a large capacitor in parallel to the battery, but is it all? I can use a power supply to replace the battery and measure the actual peak current and its duration, but what to do after that?

I am not sure using an RC circuit is a good idea and I wouldn't know if there is some active circuit that could handle the peak current.

Is there some standardized way to solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I thought about asking here because the specific application seemed like a very typical case in robotics. But I'm ok with whatever place is deemed more suitable.

Comment: @MarkBooth the answer is only partial I think, since it doesn't address the problem of how to limit the battery current when connected to the large capacitor. It's basically only half solution.

Comment: What current do the motors demand? What can the battery supply?

Comment: @BrianDrummond: I have updated the question with my current (limited) knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

> Is thee some standardized way to solve this problem?

Yes: use a capacitor.

> but is it all?

Yes.

> I can use a power supply to replace the battery and measure the actual peak current and its duration, but what to do after that?

You could estimate the necessary capacity. (I use \$U\$ for voltage, not \$V\$)

$$C={Q \over U}$$

So the question is how many <del>[Q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_%28Star_Trek%29)</del> [\$Q\$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_charge) are needed for the spike. For current you know that

$$
\begin{align}
I &={dQ \over dt}\\
Idt &= dQ\\
\underset{spike}{\int} Idt &= Q
\end{align}
$$

Basically speaking, the area under the spike tells you how many \$Q\$s you need. Of course the battery can handle some baseline current, which means a certain amount of \$Q\$s per time. The spike on top of that must be handled by the capacitor.

This is a rough estimate. Not every capacitor can take arbitrary high current spikes. Check the datasheets. Now get a capacitor with more than the estimated capacity and do your tests again. Scope the current from the battery and the current from the capacitor. The spike on the battery current should be reduced as the current for the spike comes from the capacitor.

Then put some of those capacitors in parallel to your battery. How many depends on how often a spike occurs and how fast the capacitors are recharged.

---

from the comments:

> This battery has its own built in switch: won't it cause harm to have a very large capacitor in parallel to the battery, when i turn it on? 
>   If the capacitor is large enough to sustain the spike I mentioned, won't it cause an even larger one onto the battery, when it's activated?
>   I thought I should add some small resistor in series to the capacitor. But then that too should be taken into account when calculating the value of the capacitor, right?

It depends on how you place the resistor.

- If you place it between battery and capacitor

  - it's not "getting in the way" when the capacitor unloads to balance the spike,
  - but it's always "in the way" of the battery. All current from the battery goes through the resistor, which means a permanent power loss.
- If you place it in series to the capacitor

  - it is not in the way of the current going to the motor
  - but it's in the way of the current coming from and going to the capacitor

Comment: This battery has its own built in switch: won't it cause harm to have a very large capacitor in parallel to the battery, when i turn it on? If the capacitor is large enough to sustain the spike I mentioned, won't it cause an even larger one onto the battery, when it's activated? I thought I should add some small resistor in series to the capacitor. But then that too should be taken into account when calculating the value of the capacitor, right?

Comment: Consolidating my last 4 comments.
After some more research, I think this is the most efficient solution.
Let R be a current-limiting resistor, to prevent that the capacitor shorts the battery, at battery connection, C the capacitor mentioned above, Z the impedance of the drone circuit, SSR a normally opened solid state relay that is controlled by DC levels and operates on DC currents.

Comment: Then, the impedance seen by the battery at power on is: (R // SSR_open) + (C // Z) ~ R + (C // Z), but the circuitry driving the wheels will later on close the SSR, so that the battery sees: (R // SSR_closed) + (C // Z) ~ 0 + (C // Z) = C // Z, as initially proposed. This solution could be optionally implemented with a relay instead of the SSR.

Comment: @MarkBooth: that's how I intended the comment and I *am* removing the old ones. Asking a separate question seems wrong, since I do not feel that my initial one has been answered (read the question still open wrt limiting the battery current).

Answer (score 1):

The standard solution to this problem is to limit surge current into the motors. If you are driving them with PWM then you can just ramp the PWM up at a rate slow enough to keep the surge current down. If you also measure peak current draw then you can vary the PWM ratio to stay below the current limit - then you will get the maximum available torque and acceleration. This not only protects the battery but also the motor and drive chain.

A large capacitor placed across the battery may work if the motors get up to speed fast (eg. in a slow moving vehicle with highly geared motors). But to be effective the capacitance must be very large, and then you may have problems when switching the power on.

A good Lipo battery should have no problem handling high surge currents. For example a 9800mAh battery rated at 3C (a very low rating) should be able to deliver 9.8*3 = 29A continuous. But you don't have a battery. You have a 'power box' that probably consists of a 3.7V Lipo with a boost regulator to get 12V. Its output current is limited by the regulator, and its *real* capacity is probably much less than 9800mAh.

Your power box may be able to handle high capacitance on its output - or not. Without knowledge of its internal circuit you can't be sure (and if it's a cheap Chinese unit then you can't even be sure that it will meet its specs!). Since the devices it is designed to power typically have up to 1000uF in them it should be safe to use that much capacitance, *in addition* to slowly ramping up the PWM ratio.

Comment: Yes, the "power box" I have is an El-Cheapo chinese one from ebay: I set to myself the goal of building a drone only with low cost (and yes, low quality) components, that can still be good enough. A coworker advised me that if I cascade the battery with a constant-current regulator, I can prevent the capacitors from drawing too much current at power-on. Shouldn't that allow for larger capacitance?

Comment: "constant-current regulator" is the same as "current limiter". Put it series with the motor supply _only_ (not power to control and driver circuits). Since motor current is now limited you should not need extra capacitance. However, depending on the internal circuit of the "constant current regulator", you may get significant extra voltage drop. For example if it uses an LM317 you will lose about 3V.

Comment: I've ordered some "LM2596", which turns out are LM2576: http://www.kerrywong.com/2015/07/24/lm2596-dc-dc-converter-module-testing/ but I have spare heat sinks, so heat dissipation shouldn't be a problem. Of course that's power wasted. My hope was to use the PWM limiting only to keep the motor inside its safe operating parameters, but not introduce artificial limitations caused by inability to provide peak currents that the motor would be able to tolerate.